# Ruby array with an extra state

Tags: ruby, arrays, 2d

I'm trying to go through an array and add a second dimension for true and false values in ruby.

For example.  I will be pushing on arrays to another array where it would be:

```
a = [[1,2,3,4],[5]]
```

I would like to go through each array inside of "a" and be able to mark a state of true or false for each individual value. Similar to a map from java.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What should `a` look like after you've added your booleans?

Comment: I want to go through and mark each one after I have accessed it with something.  So like 
    a =[[1->true,b->true,3,4,],5]]

Comment: So you want to turn the arrays inside `a` into hashes?

Comment: Yeah , do you think I should just turn the inner array to hashes with false values before I pop it?  I'm concerned about keeping it in place.

Comment: You _could_, or if you like just use tuples.  Then you can differentiate the unmarked ones from the ones you really wanted to make false.  I just posted a tuple-oriented answer.

Answer (score 2):

You're better off starting with this:

```
a = [{ 1 => false, 2 => false, 3 => false, 4 => false }, { 5 => false }]
```

Then you can just flip the booleans as needed. Otherwise you will have to pollute your code with a bunch of tests to see if you have a Fixnum (1, 2, ...) or a Hash (`{1 => true}`) before you can test the flag's value.

Hashes in Ruby 1.9 are ordered so you wouldn't lose your ordering by switching to hashes.

You can convert your array to this form with one of these:

```
a = a.map { |x| Hash[x.zip([false] * x.length)] }
# or
a = a.map { |x| x.each_with_object({}) { |i,h| h[i] = false } }
```

And if using `nil` to mean "unvisited" makes more sense than starting with `false` then:

```
a = a.map { |x| Hash[x.zip([nil] * x.length)] }
# or
a = a.map { |x| x.each_with_object({}) { |i,h| h[i] = nil } }
```

Some useful references:

- [`Hash[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D)
- [`each_with_object`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object)
- [`zip`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip)
- [Array `*`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-2A)

Comment: +1 Now that I think about it, hashes are prolly the way to go for this.  I wonder if the best starting value is `nil` rather than `false`, though.  It would let the OP distinguish between not-yet-tagged and I-purposely-tagged-this-false.

Comment: Yeah, thanks guys.  I will try using nil as my starting state rather than false.

Comment: @Ray: Depends how comfortable the OP is with three valued logic and whether a distinct "unvisited" state is needed. Anyway, I added some initialization options and a `nil` option.

Comment: @weez: I added some initialization options if you need to convert your original array of arrays into an array of hashes.

Comment: @muistooshort For sure if the OP *does not need* unvisited then `nil` should not be used.  +1 for pointing that out.  It is important.

Answer (score 1):

If what you are trying to do is simply tag specific elements in the member arrays with boolean values, it is just a simple matter of doing the following:

```
current_value = a[i][j]
a[i][j] = [current_value, true_or_false]
```

For example if you have

```
a = [[1,2,3,4],[5]]
```

Then if you say

```
a[0][2] = [a[0,2],true]
```

then `a` becomes

```
a = [[1,2,[3,true],4],[5]]
```

You can roll this into a method

```
def tag_array_element(a, i, j, boolean_value)
    a[i][j] = [a[i][j], boolean_value]
end
```

You might want to enhance this a little so you don't tag a specific element twice. :)  To do so, just check if `a[i][j]` is already an array.

Comment: Ok, awesome.  I wasn't aware of tuples... I think that will do the trick.  Thanks for the speedy response.  I would vote up by I don't have any rep.  Thanks though

Comment: Careful, you don't want to get parenthesitis.

Answer (score 0):

Change `x % 2 == 0` for the actual operation you want for the mapping:

```
>> xss = [[1,2,3,4],[5]]
>> xss.map { |xs| xs.map { |x| {x => x % 2} } } 
#=> [[{1=>false}, {2=>true}, {3=>false}, {4=>true}], [{5=>false}]]
```